# How to connect monitors

Tags: power-supply, hdmi, vga, cable, displayport

If I want to have 2 monitors connected and a laptop. Do I need to have VGA, HDMI, DisplayPort and Power cable in both displays? Or is it enough with only power cable for 1 monitor and all cables to the 2nd monitor (VGA, HDMI, Displayport, Power Cable?

Comment: Each monitor needs power. Each monitor needs a signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per monitor you need a powercable and one of the other types: VGA, HDMI or Displayport.

Do note, VGA does not have a high bandwidth, and depending on the monitor, you may not get a high enough resolution. VGA (D-SUB) supports up to 1920x1200. Displayport is preferred, but HDMI will work well too.

EDIT: by reading the comment exchange in the other answer, you may want to consider a USB docking station which has connectivity for 2 monitors. Then you only need to plug in the usb cable to your laptop, install the drivers, and you have support for 2 additional monitors.

Comment: I have for one monitor: Powercable, VGA, HDMI and Display, and for another monitor Powercable and HDMI. would this work well? In case someone brings a old computer which needs VGA?

Comment: Yes, for the first monitor you only need one of the 3 connector cables, but you can keep them handy in case you want to connect an old computer.

Comment: ok tnx. I thought maybe you needed also to have in handy for monitor number two VGA. Than i got it. Monitor 1: Powercable, VGA, HDMI and Displayport cable in handy. And for the other monitor only powercable and HDMI plugged in

Comment: Yes. Feel free to mark any of the answers as the solution, so others know you no longer need help. Also consider upvoting if you have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: good idea.Better of using a USB docking station. so i need to do this: Powercable and HDMI, DisplayPort, or VGA in first monitor. And other monitor USB cable from screen to laptop and Powercable and HDMI, Display or VGA cable in 2nd monitor. hmm

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following:

- Power cable between mains and monitor 1
- Power cable between mains and monitor 2
- Video cable between computer and monitor 1
- Video cable between computer and monitor 2

Video cables can't transport power, both monitors need to be powered independently. Both monitors need to be connected to the video output of the computer, you can't daisy-chain monitors. Also, your computer *must* have 2 video outputs, as one output can only be connected to one monitor. Exceptions to these exist and cost money.

VGA, HDMI and DVI are 3 types of video cables. DisplayPort is a type of connector that can be converted (via an appropriate adapter) to one of the 3 former.

Now, how to recognize which video cable you need:

- Display port is a rectangular port with a "D"-like logo near it
- HDMI is has the shape of a trapezoid with bent sides, and a single line of connectors in the middle (should also have an HDMI logo nearby).
- DVI is a long trapezoid with square holes, and a line- or cross-shaped slit on one side, *usually* colored white
- VGA is a trapezoid with three rows of round holes, *usually* colored blue

Depending on your computer and your monitors, you may need to buy additional adapters - these shouldn't cost much.

Comment: its a laptop. So you mean for one monitor you only need power cable and HDMI? reason why i connect all cables for one monitor is if someone have a old laptop that dosent support HDMI or Displayport. So i also plugged inn VGA

Comment: If it's a laptop, then the laptop monitor already has both power and video cables wired through the hinges. Most (if not all) laptops also have a video output for an additional monitor, HDMI or DisplayPort for most modern laptops and VGA for almost all of them. I suggest you use VGA anyway, unless your external monitor is a 4k TV screen.

Comment: its 23.8" screen. I think most laptop only have 1 VGA output. So i can maybe use HDMI Cable istead of VGA

Comment: You cannot use an HDMI cable if the laptop only has VGA output. What you can do is use a VGA <--> HDMI converter.

Comment: Yes. if the laptop only have 1 VGA output than i need two VGA output for 2 monitors. I think old computers usually have only 1 VGA output so i need most likely a HDMI converter. The thing is someone has new computers and others has old computers